# How to deploy Sonarqube Server on Heroku Dyno

Tags: heroku, sonarqube

I have to deploy a SonarQube server on Heroku Web Dyno.

For this I have tried below items:

1. Downloaded the SonarQube Community Edition from
   https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/
2. Then I unzipped the folder and went into /sonarqube-7.8/ folder
3. Then I have created the Procfile with following content:

> web: chmod u+x bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh &&
>   ./bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh

4. Then I have created the system.properties file with below content:

> ```
> java.runtime.version=1.8
> ```

5. Then I ran below commands to check in the SonarQube Server on Heroku Git and 
   ran the server:

> ```
> git init
> git add.
> git commit -m "initial commit"
> git push heroku master
> ```

The git bash console shows following after running the above mentioned commands:

```
Enumerating objects: 6, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 391 bytes | 39.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> SonarQubeFramework app detected
remote: -----> Create setupSonar.sh
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 195.5M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v8
remote:        https://<app_name>.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/<app_name>.git
   cad2f14..55d4bcd  master -> master
```

And I am getting below logs from on heroku

```
2019-06-28T10:54:19.321815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `chmod u+x bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh && ./bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh`
2019-06-28T10:54:21.360549+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-06-28T10:54:21.380868+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-06-28T10:54:21.313195+00:00 app[web.1]: Usage: ./bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh { console | start | stop | force-stop | restart | status | dump }
```

**Can anyone help me in deploying SonarQube Server on Heroku Cloud??**

Comment: The immediate problem is clearly stated in the error message: `Usage: ./bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh { console | start | stop | force-stop | restart | status | dump }`. Your `Procfile` just tries to run `./bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh` without any argument. But are you sure that SonarQube will run properly on Heroku? Does it respect the `PORT` environment variable? Will it be happy with an ephemeral filesystem?

Comment: Thanks @Chris, for highlighting this. I am not sure that SonarQube would be able to run in Heroku properly, I have to figure out the solution of the PORT problem that you have highlighted.

Comment: I suspect that Heroku is a bad fit here. You'll have better luck with a VPS. But if you want to keep trying, start by updating your `Procfile` to add a command. I'm guessing that it should contain `web: chmod u+x bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh && ./bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start`.

Comment: Actually I am working on PoC and I have to tell whether SonarQube can be run on Heroku or Not, so I have to try all possible ways to run it on Heroku. I have updated the Procfile and ran it, now I am getting another error `Failed to start SonarQube.`. I think its related to SonarQube configuration, may be JVM setting or PORT setting. I am checking it and will update here if I figured out something. Thanks @Chris

Comment: Have also a look at the SonarQube log files for more (failure) information.

Comment: I am able to Deploy the SonarQube Server successfully and its working perfectly fine and gets integrated with GitLab as well seamlessly.
@Chris after using SonarQube, I don't think it doesn't go well with Heroku Cloud.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am able to deploy the SonarQube server on Heroku Cloud:
Below are the commands to be executed in the same order:

```
heroku create <appName>
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev -a <appName>
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/NayaraCaetano/heroku-buildpack-sonarqube.git -a <appName>
mkdir <appName> && cd <appName>
touch README
git init
heroku git:remote -a <appName>
git add .
git commit -am "initial commit"
git push heroku master
heroku dyno:resize performance-m -a <appName>
```

> **Note:** You have to use **performance-m** dyno (which is not free) on Heroku due to some memory constraints. Also free version of
>   Postgres will get exhausted within 1 or 2 scans, so you have to
>   upgrade it as per your need.